# Saving into Local Storage with a Click Event

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello stackoverflow:  I am working on getting a click event save into local storage.  However, I get that it is undefined as the answer.  This is what I have so far as my click event:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

    $(".btnlocalStorage").on("click", function() {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("I am clicked!")
       var myContent = $(this).(".btnlocalStorage").val();
       localStorage.setItem("myContent", myContent);
       //localStorage.setItem("myContent", JSON.stringify(myContent));
    })
    
})
```

This is the HTML part of it, a button and a text area:

```
 <textarea type="text" class="TextBoxColors-17 form-control" id="TextBoxStorage-17" aria-label="5:00 PM" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm"></textarea>
            
   <button class="btn btn-primary btnlocalStorage" type="button" todo="saveToDo-11am"><i class="fa fa-floppy-o" style="font-size:18px;"></i>
   </button>
```

What should happen is that when I type any content into the text area, when I click the save button, this content should be saved into local storage. I am getting the key name, but the value/content undefined.  Please, help me get this working. Thanks!

Comment: This is a syntax error: `$(this).(".btnlocalStorage").val();`. What value are you trying to get?

Comment: `$(this).prev().val()` will get the value of the textarea before the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to get the value of your button instead of the value of the textarea with:

> $(this)

Your code should look like this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btnlocalStorage").on("click", function() {
        localStorage.setItem("myContent", $(".TextBoxColors-17").val());
        console.log(localStorage.getItem("myContent"));
    })
});
```

EDIT :

This code only works for one specific textarea, if you want to make it work for multiple textareas followed by a button, you must use :

> $(this).prev()

"this" refers to the button wich triggered the event and the prev() function allow you to get the element just before it.

Be careful, your local storage item must have a different name from one button to another, otherwise all buttons will override the same item content, for the example I took the ID of your textarea but it can be any iterated variable :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btnlocalStorage").on("click", function() {
        localStorage.setItem($(this).prop("id"), $(this).prev().val());
        console.log(localStorage.getItem($(this).prop("id")));
    })
});
```

Comment: Hello Jimmy: Thanks for your reply.  It does work, however, just for one of my textareas.  I really have about nine of them.  I did not mention that before because I thought it was not necessary.  These are two of them.  How do I make it work for all of my text areas.  It is currently working just for one.

Comment: `<textarea type="text" class="TextBoxColors-16 form-control" id="TextBoxStorage-16" aria-label="4:00 PM" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm"></textarea>
 <button class="btn btn-primary btnlocalStorage" type="button" todo="saveToDo-10am"><i class="fa fa-floppy-o" style="font-size:18px;"></i>
        </button>`

Comment: `<textarea type="text" class="TextBoxColors-17 form-control" id="TextBoxStorage-17" aria-label="5:00 PM" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm"></textarea>
   <button class="btn btn-primary btnlocalStorage" type="button" todo="saveToDo-11am"><i class="fa fa-floppy-o" style="font-size:18px;"></i>
 </button>`

Comment: This is currently working for me, but when I try it with a class, only one button works:

Comment: `$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btnlocalStorage").on("click", function() {
    localStorage.setItem("myContent14", $("#TextBoxStorage-14").val());
    localStorage.setItem("myContent15", $("#TextBoxStorage-15").val());
    localStorage.setItem("myContent16", $("#TextBoxStorage-16").val());
    localStorage.setItem("myContent17", $("#TextBoxStorage-17").val());
  console.log(localStorage.getItem("myContent14"));
  console.log(localStorage.getItem("myContent15"));
  console.log(localStorage.getItem("myContent16"));
  console.log(localStorage.getItem("myContent17"));
    })
});`

Comment: Thanks for your help, Jimmy.  I took your answer as the accepted answer because it really answered my original question.  Thanks again!  :-)

Comment: Thanks a bunch, Jimmy!  After editing your answer, it works for all buttons.